# An example of a pseudo-radial space which is not a sequential space.

Tags: general-topology

Can someone give an example of a pseudo-radial topological space which is not a sequential topological space? I have heard that not every sequential space is a pseudo-radial space, but I have never seen an example.

Comment: Look for the paper where pseudo-radial was first defined. It probably has a motivating example.

Comment: BTW in that paper (in Fund. Math. by Herrlich, in German), indeed ordinal spaces like my example were mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\omega_1+1$ in the order topology is even radial (stronger than pseudo-radial), compact Hausdorff but *not* sequential. ($\omega_1$ is sequentially closed but not closed).